# Using java AOT /native compilation with openfeign 2022.0.2

Tags: java, spring, openfeign, spring-native

I read that starting spring-cloud 2022.0.0, you can use native compilation. I'm using 2022.0.2 (spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:4.0.2), but when I use an OpenFeign client with native compilation, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'boxedHelloController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'helloWorldClient': Error creating bean with name 'nl.cqit.function.poc.java.helloworld.controller.HelloWorldClient': Post-processing of FactoryBean''s singleton object failed
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.AutowiredFieldValueResolver.resolveValue(AutowiredFieldValueResolver.java:195) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.AutowiredFieldValueResolver.resolveAndSet(AutowiredFieldValueResolver.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at nl.cqit.function.poc.java.boxedhello.controller.BoxedHelloController__Autowiring.apply(BoxedHelloController__Autowiring.java:15) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.InstanceSupplier$1.get(InstanceSupplier.java:83) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:947) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:3.0.5]
        at nl.cqit.function.poc.java.boxedhello.Main.main(Main.java:12) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nl.cqit.function.poc.java.helloworld.controller.HelloWorldClient': Post-processing of FactoryBean''s singleton object failed
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:108) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1823) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1273) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:259) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1640) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1597) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.AutowiredFieldValueResolver.resolveValue(AutowiredFieldValueResolver.java:189) ~[na:na]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Proxy class defined by interfaces [interface nl.cqit.function.poc.java.helloworld.controller.HelloWorldClient, interface org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy, interface org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised, interface org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy] not found. Generating proxy classes at runtime is not supported. Proxy classes need to be defined at image build time by specifying the list of interfaces that they implement. To define proxy classes use -H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=<comma-separated-config-files> and -H:DynamicProxyConfigurationResources=<comma-separated-config-resources> options.
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unsupportedFeature(VMError.java:89) ~[na:na]
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.reflect.proxy.DynamicProxySupport.getProxyClass(DynamicProxySupport.java:171) ~[na:na]
        at java.base@19.0.2/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyConstructor(Proxy.java:47) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:na]
        at java.base@19.0.2/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:1037) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:123) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.java:127) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:434) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1885) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:105) ~[boxedhello-app.exe:6.0.7]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
```

Here is my API interface:

```java
package nl.cqit.function.poc.java.helloworld.api;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import nl.cqit.function.poc.java.helloworld.api.model.Person;
import nl.cqit.function.poc.java.helloworld.api.model.Problem;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@Validated
@Tag(
    name = "HelloWorld",
    description = "the HelloWorld API"
)
public interface HelloWorldApi {
    @Operation(
        operationId = "sayHello",
        summary = "The main function",
        description = "This endpoint will call sayHello",
        tags = {"HelloWorld"},
        responses = {@ApiResponse(
    responseCode = "200",
    description = "OK",
    content = {@Content(
    mediaType = "application/json",
    schema = @Schema(
    implementation = String.class
)
), @Content(
    mediaType = "application/problem+json",
    schema = @Schema(
    implementation = String.class
)
)}
), @ApiResponse(
    responseCode = "400",
    description = "input validation failed",
    content = {@Content(
    mediaType = "application/json",
    schema = @Schema(
    implementation = Problem.class
)
), @Content(
    mediaType = "application/problem+json",
    schema = @Schema(
    implementation = Problem.class
)
)}
)}
    )
    @RequestMapping(
        method = {RequestMethod.POST},
        value = {"/helloWorld"},
        produces = {"application/json", "application/problem+json"},
        consumes = {"application/json"}
    )
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    String sayHello(@Parameter(name = "Person",description = "",required = true) @RequestBody @Valid Person var1);
}
```

And here is my Feign client:

```java
package nl.cqit.function.poc.java.helloworld.controller;

import nl.cqit.function.poc.java.helloworld.api.HelloWorldApi;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;

@FeignClient(name = "helloWorldClient", url = "http://localhost:8080")
public interface HelloWorldClient extends HelloWorldApi {
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```java
package nl.cqit.function.poc.java.boxedhello.impl;

import nl.cqit.function.poc.java.boxedhello.api.BoxedHelloApi;
import nl.cqit.function.poc.java.boxedhello.api.model.Person;
import nl.cqit.function.poc.java.helloworld.controller.HelloWorldClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BoxedHelloImpl implements BoxedHelloApi {

    @Autowired
    private HelloWorldClient helloWorldClient;

    @Override
    public String sayHello(Person person) {
        String greeting = helloWorldClient.sayHello(map(person));
        String horizontalEdge = "+" + "-".repeat(greeting.length() + 2) + "+";
        return horizontalEdge + "\n| " + greeting + " |\n" + horizontalEdge;
    }

    private nl.cqit.function.poc.java.helloworld.api.model.Person map(Person person) {
        return new nl.cqit.function.poc.java.helloworld.api.model
                .Person(person.getFirstName())
                .lastName(person.getLastName());
    }
}
```

With this as my Main class:

```java
package nl.cqit.function.poc.java.boxedhello;

import nl.cqit.function.poc.java.helloworld.controller.HelloWorldClient;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;

@EnableFeignClients(basePackageClasses = {HelloWorldClient.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Using this profile for native compilation in my pom.xml:

```xml
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <image>
                                <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                                <env>
                                    <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                                </env>
                            </image>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>process-aot</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>process-aot</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
                            <metadataRepository>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                            </metadataRepository>
                            <requiredVersion>22.3</requiredVersion>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>add-reachability-metadata</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>add-reachability-metadata</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Spring Boot 3.0.6. Try downgrading to 3.0.5, that should resolve the issue. At least until there is a Spring Boot version that fixes this problem.

Comment: I should have said, but I actually was using 3.0.5